# text-decoration: none; is not doing anything

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to have a link show up in white, without an underline. The text color shows up correctly as white, but the blue underline is stubbornly persisting. I tried text-decoration: none; and text-decoration: none !important; in the CSS to remove the link underline. Neither worked.

All the code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forum</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="body">
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4 box">
<div class="border5">Categories</div>
<div class="border_box category_cat">NETWORK ANNOUNCEMENTS</div>
<a href="http://localhost/forum/view_category.php?cid=3">
<li class="border3">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Hide And Seek<span class="label label-info left">0</span></li></a>
<div class="border_box category_cat">GENERAL</div>
<div href="" class="border text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Questions<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div href="" class="border3 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Bugs<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div class="border_box category_cat">HIDE AND SEEK</div>
<div href="" class="border3 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> General Discussions<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div href="" class="border1 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>  Suggestions And Feedback<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div href="" class="border1 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Bugs<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div class="border_box category_cat">OFF TOPIC</div>
<div href="" class="border3 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Minecraft<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div href="" class="border1 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>  Non-Gaming<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div href="" class="border1 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Gaming<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div class="border_box category_cat">REPORTS AND APPEALS</div>
<div href="" class="border3 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Player Reports<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
<div href="" class="border6 text">&#8627; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Appeals<span class="label label-info left">0</span></div>
</div>
<div class="span8">
<h3>My First Forum!</h3>
<hr />
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    echo "<form action='login_parse.php' method='post'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username' />&nbsp;
    Password: <input type='password' name='password' />&nbsp;
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Log In' />
    ";

} else {
    echo "<p>You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username']." &bull; <a href='logout_parse.php'>Logout</a>";
}
?>

<hr />
<div id="content">
<?php
include_once("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY topic_date ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$topics='';
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['topic_title'];
        $cid = $row['category_id'];
        $topics .= "<a href='view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$title."<font size='-1'></font></a>";
    }
    echo $topics;
} else {
    echo "<p>There are no topics available yet.</p>";
}
?>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
</div>
</div>
```

All the css code:

```
.cat_links {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #000000;
}
.cat_links:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
.border {
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #0088cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.text {
    color: #0088cc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.border1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
    color: #0088cc;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.border2 {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
    color: #0088cc;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.category_cat {
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: inherit;
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    color: #888;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
        background-color: #FFF;
}
.border3 {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.left {
    float: right;
}
.label-info:hover {
    background-color: #2d6987;
}
.label:hover {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.box_cat {
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
}
.border3:hover {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.border:hover {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.border1:hover {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.border2:hover {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.border6:hover {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.border_box {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #888;
        background-color: #FFF;
}
.border5 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
    color: #0088cc;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    background-color: whiteSmoke;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.body {
    background-color: #C12727;
}
.box {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.border6 {
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 33px;
    color: #0088cc;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.span4 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.border3 a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: You can't wrap list items in anchor tags.

Comment: everything is working in css and the code without the text-decoration: none;....

Comment: Just because it seems to work doesn't mean it's valid code, and invalid code can cause more problems because the rules that should be applied cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: If after all of that you still see the underline, maybe there's an external application or browser plugin underlining the link. Skype, Google voice, etc, they all underline text/links that they can use to call for example. There may be many types of applications that underline other things too. Or even your browser is configured to always underline all links, and that overwrites the page css

Comment: I did remove all off my bootstrap files and then it did work but i need the bootstrap files.

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap css file before or after your own css? You should load before.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid (you can't wrap an anchor around a list item) but this CSS will fix your issue:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LwstQ/)

Comment: that is not happening on my side.. :/

Comment: What is not happening on you side?

Comment: the line is still there

Comment: Well as you can see by the jsFiddle it works. If it's not working for you then you probably have other CSS and HTML (and maybe even JavaScript) that could be causing issues. Consider revising your question to include more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just styling links in general directly ?

```
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Or

```
.border3 a { 
text-decoration: none;
    }
```

If you want only that property on those links in particular

Answer (score 1):

Just Use

```
a{text-decoration: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `text-decoration: none` to a list not the link.
It should be:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor element should be inside the List element:

```
<li class="border3"><a href="#">Something</a></li>
```

not the other way around.

And then you can apply the CSS as Dikeneko said

```
.border3 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```